# what is the best way to make money on the side as a beginning author?

Tags: novel, money

I am a new author and as I am writing my novels, I need a little revenue.
Are there sites that would pay for articles being written?
Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: The best way to make money as a beginning author is to have a day job. *Which* day job is left as an exercise for the student. :)

Comment: I agree completely with Lauren Ipsum. Unless you're hired out of school to write for some larger group, such as being a technical writer, journalist, copy-editor, etc, writing isn't your main job, until it is. Freelancing rarely earns you a living wage right off the bat unless you're very lucky.

Comment: Back when I was writing magazine articles, I once calculated that if you took the money that I was paid divided by the time it took me to write them, I was making about $2 per hour. I'm afraid to even do the calculation for my books.

Answer (score 9):

**I advise against writing as a side job for a writer.**

To write your novels (or whatever) you need a special kind of creativity and mental energy. You only have a limited amount of this, before it runs out each day. Most writers notice that after a certain time writing the quality of their ideas and writing deteriorates. What they need is to take a break and replenish their creativity and mental writing energy by not-writing.

If you earn money writing, you'll have less creativity and mental energy left for your essential writing: that of your novel. I once tried to write a novel while studying, but researching, structuring, developing and writing my seminar papers took away all the creativity and mental energy that I had. I had lots of time, but I wrote not a single word for my novel in a whole year. But taking off a month from my studies for NaNoWriMo, I wrote a 50.000 words first draft in ten days.

If you don't mind taking forever to finish your novel while wasting your creativity on writing stuff you don't care about, then that's no problem, but since you probably want to make a living as a writer of novels, you might want to find a non-writing side job, like @dmm recommends in his answer, and focus your whole writing energy on writing what you want to write.

What I would do is: deliver the mail, bake fries at Mac D., do lawn mowing and gardening. The best side job for a writer, in my opinion, is mentally effortless, relatively stressfree, and physically invigorating. I've been driving taxi (during the day, chauffeuring old people to the doctor and such), delivering parcels, and working as a gardener's help. Great jobs to be creative alongside. Think "student job".

**And I recommend that you find a job that leaves you time to write whenever you have your most creative time.**

Most people find that they are the most creative and mentally fresh before lunch. So find a job that starts after lunch. Others love to write at night. So find a job in the morning or afternoon (however long you need to sleep), relax a bit or do sports, then write in the evening. Or whatever suits you. Just don't give your best time away for your moneymaking. Scedule your money job at your most useless time.

Comment: Software programming. By far, it offers the greatest combination of income and flexibility. Full-time employment should be your highest priority. Financial stress can induce creative stress. Successful authors who didn't have a full-time job (or other financial support) when they began making significant income from publishing are rare. Mythic rare. Good luck!

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer and some awesome insights. I had never considered a limited amount of creative writing or writing times, though both seem obvious now that you've mentioned them.

Answer (score 3):

1) Try to find something that requires lots of time but little hands-on time, like house-sitting, pet-sitting, old-people-sitting, and infant-sitting.  (But NOT child-sitting!)  Or night watchman.  The pay will be lousy (minimum wage or less), but you'll have lots of free time doing it, so you can do it a lot.  You can work 12 hours a day at jobs like that, without giving up much writing time.

2) It is impossible to answer your question about sites that pay for articles, without knowing your other talents.  Many magazine/e-zine articles would require the author to have some bona fides in fashion, science, technology, food/dining, crafting, travel, etc.

3) If you are good at science, there are companies that pay people to take journal submissions written in poor English and turn them into journal submissions written in good English.

4) NOBODY is going to pay an unknown freelancer to *write* an article for them.  They MIGHT pay for an *already-written* article.

Answer (score 1):

There's [elance.com](http://elance.com) and [odesk.com](http://odesk.com). They're online freelancing, and there's sections for writers to pick up jobs like copywriting, article writing, translating, etc.

However, you have to be aware of a couple things. First, companies are often unrealistic about what they expect and what your work is worth. You may get paid in pennies. Second, writers are often unrealistic about what they expect and what their work is worth. You shouldn't expect to buy a mansion any time soon. But it's definitely an option and worth checking out.

I've heard of creative types in LA taking up driving for car services like Uber or Lyft as a day job. It doesn't give you time to write on the job, of course, but hours are flexible and it doesn't require an excess of mental energy. That's what you want in a day job when you're just starting out: something that won't drain you or take up all your time.

Answer (score 0):

on guru.com there is always a bunch of people paying (not very much) for ghost writing, this is a way to sharpen your writing skills and make a little money on the side.